# Will an object reference to an object of a class A having another object of class B as its instance variable, also point to the object of type B?

Tags: java, class, oop

An object reference, say r is declared for a class, say A. Class A also has the object reference instance variable, v to another class B. So when the object reference to class A is defined, then r will start pointing to a template of class A (object A). The problem is whether the instance variable v, will also start referencing to a template of B. (This will only be possible if an object of type B is also created, so a sub - question might be whether object of type B is also created.)

```
public class A {
    B v;
}

public class B {
    //code related to B
}

public class C {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        A r = new A();
        //Will r.v be created?
        //Will it point to a B object
    }
}
```

The problem is in context with Java Language.

Comment: Hint: add `System.out.println(r.v);` to your main method, then execute the code, and you'll know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the provided code, `r.v` will remain `null` by default, since you are not assigning anything to it.

In order for `v` to hold a reference to an object of class `B`, you'll have to add somewhere `v = new B ();`.

For example, you can add that statement in `A`'s constructor:

```
public class A {
    B v;

    public A ()
    {
        this.v = new B ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, got you! so if this constructor is added and an object created, will r point to object of type B also?

Comment: @SukritKapil No, `r` references an object of type `A`. That objects contains an instance variable `v` that may reference an object of type `B`.